# Make 5kV, 0.001A (5W) step-up from 12V?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

I have faced that problem:
9-15V Vin (12V accu) and 5kV, 0.001A out (5W)
and dont know how to solve that, i tried to use push-pull SG3525 but efficiency is very poor, about 20-30%. Can someone suggest me what IC/topology to use? I even tried capacitor charger but with no luck too:(
What i did more was sepic step-up with voltage multiplier (mc34063 :) ) but Ton/Toff is too big i think and i can reach only 1.6kV...
Please give me, if you can, any piece of advice...

best regards

Comment: You want to Google Cockcroft–Walton generator. I've personally built devices going over 10KV using this method. Could be risky, though, so make sure you know what you are doing or buy one ready made and still be super careful.

Comment: An easy shortcut to many kV from 12v is an automotive ignition coil, switched by a basic oscillator/timer circuit. Bosch BIP373 drivers are a good bet for driving them, although some modern coil-on-plug packs have drivers built in and just need 12v, GND, and a logic-level trigger signal.

Answer (score 4):

At that high of a step-up ratio, I'd look into a transformer doing most of the work.  With the right windings, you can drive the primary from a H bridge straight from the 9-15 V DC.  Another option at such low input voltage is a center tapped primary.  The center tap is connected to the DC input power, and each end has a low side switch, which alternately pull low.

With a few 100 kHz square wave on the input, it wouldn't require a very large transformer at all to push 5 W out.  The whole circuit with transformer should be able to fit easily in the palm or your hand.

The way you do regulation is by making sure that the minimum voltage square wave (when your input is on 9 V) can cause the 5 kV at 1 mA out.  On the output side you put something that measures whatever quantity you want to regulate, and drives a opto-isolator when it is over the limit.  On the input side, you simply kill the oscillation whenever the opto is active.

From what you say, you don't seem to actually need isolation, but at 5 kV that is a good idea for safety.  You could get the same power out with a auto-transformer, but then the output wouldn't be isolated.  Unless this is going into a very controlled situation or a totally sealed box, I'd consider the extra safety from full isolation to be a good tradeoff.

Comment: Now i have working 5kV from 2V (two volts) cyclon accu, on sg3525 it takes 1.1A at no load (divider only), but quickly takes to 4Amps with load so... i decided to use 12V accu, i can get about 1.5kV from 12V/0.055A ... the point is... my knowledge is to small to calculate correct transformer and frequency for such dc-dc converter. I think best solution is e.g. sg3525 push-pull with transformer but i dont know how to calculate power if i have to use voltage multiplier on the output of transformer...

Answer (score 3):

5W at high voltage is prime territory for a flyback topology converter.

The [LT3751](http://www.linear.com/docs/27024) can be used as a controller, for example. The flyback magnetics looks like a transformer, but it's actually used as a multi-winding inductor.

[Here](http://powerelectronics.com/site-files/powerelectronics.com/files/archive/powerelectronics.com/mag/Keith%20Billings%20April%202003.pdf) is a useful article on designing flyback transformers (Billings' book has a lot more information). You'll need a gapped core for a flyback.

Comment: Thank you! You are wizard or so? :) i am just reading pdf of lt3751! :) will buy it tomorrow and try to use it. But also will try to use sg3525 again too... will check what will be better...

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've done this: -

- Designed a simple buck regulator that can be controlled to produce an output voltage in the range of under 1 volts to nearly 12 volts. This is the way the output of the high voltage is controlled. Linear Technology produce a very usable PWM chip that is voltage in and duty cycle out - this can feed two FETs wired synchronously. (Circa 95% efficiency at approximately 100 kHz is quite achievable)
- The above voltage is fed to the centre tap of the primary winding of a transformer
- The primary winding outers are grounded by low on resistance MOSFETs alternatively at (say) 50 kHz. Sufficient care to ensure that the two on states do not overlap -  a little bit of logic and an RC filter can easily ensure this.
- The secondary side HAS to be wound to avoid significant resonance at 50 kHz or there will be a few scorched parts. This is the tricky bit and I'd aim for a voltage of around 2 to 3kV peak.
- Then I'd use a cockcroft walton diode multiplier

The same idea as above I used to generate 50 kV for an X-ray tube power supply.

Use a simulator to death for this - wind a typical secondary - measure its resonant frequency - plug the numbers into the simulator and maybe rejig the final stage operating frequency to make it a bit lower. Read up on low self capacitance transformer windings and get a reel of that yellow tape for separating the layers of the secondary but, the main thing is

TAKE DAMN CARE because this output can be lethal.

Comment: I've done something similar too, also for a x-ray tube power supply.  In that case, the transformer put out around what the OP wants, and the cockroft-walton brought it up to 55 kV.  That's why I think this can be simplified by eliminating the cockroft-walton in this case.